# How to add items in a scrambled style in a recyclerview like gmail app

Tags: android

What is the best way to implement the following:
Add selected items from a spinner in a scrambled way, where I could remove or rearrange items like in the gmail app. I'm not sure how to do this. Shall I use a recyclerview or a listview to add the selected item? Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Please refer the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a **Tag View**. Android doesn't have this view widget but you can use a 3rd party library like [AndroidTagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView). Once the dependencies are added you can use the layout like below,

```
  <com.skyhope.materialtagview.TagView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_show_more"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement TagView and came across a problem. Can you please have a look at it please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58732160/java-lang-runtimeexception-illegal-position-in-tagview