# java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal position! in TagView

Tags: android

[TagView](https://github.com/whilu/AndroidTagView) library is used in the app that I'm developing. I'm adding the tags from an ArrayList which I get from a [MultiSelectDialog](https://github.com/abumoallim/Android-Multi-Select-Dialog). The tags I'm adding to the TagView does have an id associated with it. *id* values are important for me to maintain. But when I pass the id to addTag() method it throws a error at runtime `java.lang.RuntimeException: Illegal position!`
 Maybe I'm doing something wrong. What is the best way to maintain the values of id I get from the onSelected() while adding to tag. Appreciate your time.

```
.onSubmit(new MultiSelectDialog.SubmitCallbackListener() {
@Override
public void onSelected(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds, ArrayList<String> selectedNames, String dataString) {
    //will return list of selected IDS

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIds.size(); i++) {
        Toast.makeText(MessageComposeActivity.this, "Selected Ids : " + selectedIds.get(i) + "\n" +
                "Selected Names : " + selectedNames.get(i) + "\n" +
                "DataString : " + dataString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("KLKL",String.valueOf(selectedIds));
        //Adding tags
        mTagContainerLayout2.addTag(selectedNames.get(i), selectedIds.get(i));

    }

}

@Override
public void onCancel() {
    Log.d("Cancel","Dialog cancelled");

}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will be thrown under the following circumstances:

```
 private void onAddTag(String text, int position) {
        if (position < 0 || position > mChildViews.size()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Illegal position!");
        }
```

**From your code:**

```
mTagContainerLayout2.addTag(selectedNames.get(i), selectedIds.get(i));
```

You are trying to add tags to a position which doesn't exists inside the TagView layout.

`onAddTag(String text, int position)` is useful if you already have a list of TagView and you want to add a new item in between or at the end of the list.

**Use**

`mTagContainerLayout.addTag(String text);` for adding single item.

**Or**

`mTagContainerLayout.setTags(List<String> tags);` for adding multiple items.

**How indexing works?**

`id` for the tags will auto increase based on indexing starting from 0. You might be wondering how to detect the `MultiSelectDialog` `id` along with the `TagView` `id`? For this you can use a `HashMap` with `MultiSelectDialog` **id** as `key` and `TagView` **id** as `value`.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

.onSubmit(new MultiSelectDialog.SubmitCallbackListener() {
@Override
public void onSelected(ArrayList<Integer> selectedIds, ArrayList<String> selectedNames, String dataString) {
    //Adding tags
    mTagContainerLayout2.addTag(selectedNames());

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedIds.size(); i++) {
        hashMap.add(selectedIds.get(i), i);
    }
}
```

To get the `id` of a TagView item by the `id` of MultiSelectDialog

```
int selectedTagView = hashMap.get(multiSelectDialogId);
```